# What exactly is the responsibility of the "ICryptoKeyStore" implementation in DotNetOpenAuth?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I've got a sample up and running, however I do not understand what exactly the ICryptoKeyStore implementation is used for. What is it storing exactly, and in what context are it's methods invoked?

I have tried reading the source code of DNOA, however it would take too much time to grasp all the contextual details.

I just want to know, **what does DNOA use the implementation for?**

Comment: http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/DotNetOpenAuth.Ultimate/DotNetOpenAuth/ICryptoKeyStore

Comment: @iamkrillin I've already read that, but it does not explain what it's for exactly - whats a bucket? Why do I need to implement this? Etc.

Comment: Jeff, did you ever find out the answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I think I might have grasped it.

The crypto keys are used when en/decrypting a token. The first part of the token is the `Handle`, and DNOA uses this to look up the key that was used for encrypting a particular token.

You will notice that when using an in-memory store, when it is wiped, all access tokens will be invalidated, because DNOA can no longer decrypt them due to the missing keys.